# Does a healing spell provoke an opportunity attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack, healing

I can't find a clear answer for my question.. The PHB said regarding OAs:

> The opportunity attack action is provoked by an enemy leaving an adjacent square without shifting or teleporting, or by an adjacent enemy using a ranged or area power. [PH:290]

With that in mind, I'm wondering if a healing spell, like Inspiring Word, is counted as a area power?

Inspiring Word:

> Encounter (Special) ✦ martial, healing
>   Minor Action
>   Close burst 5

So, considering that a close burst is an area power, if a player tries to heal someone, would he provoke OAs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Close bursts do not provoke opportunity attacks.

As you mentioned, only ranged and area attacks provoke. There are 4 kinds of attacks (in terms of range/targeting): melee, ranged, close, and area. Close attacks, which are either "close burst X" or "close blast X" are different from area attacks, which are usually "area burst X" (or occasionally "area wall X"). Thus, close attacks do not provoke OAs.